# Sum n random numbers (for simulation purposes)

Tags: excel, algorithm, random, excel-formula

Is it possible to define a named field in Excel filled with a vector of random numbers, with only **one** formula?

In the case where I want to have only one random number I can define a named field called  `random` having the value of `=RND()` Now I want to create a named field `random_vector` containing a vector of `n` random values. A canonical way would be to define a named field by `OFFSET(RND();0;0;n)` but this doesn't work.

This problem could easily be done by filling a column with my random numbers and then define a named field over this column. This solution would not work because I have to fill many cells with a formula.

**Background of the question**

One application of this is that I want to compute in an easy way the sum (or product, or quantile,...) of n random variables. For example, I can compute the sum of 5 uniform random numbers by the formula

```
=RND()+RND()+RND()+RND()+RND()
```

It I now want to compute the sum of 50 uniform random variables, I could extend this formula to contain 50 terms `RND()` but it would be a mess.

**Some precisions**

- I greatly appreciate your help since I have to implement this in Excel without VBA or addons (otherwise I would code this in C++ and then link it to Excel)
- The sum of uniform random variables in not an uniform distribution.
- Anyway I am **not** interessed in the sum of uniform random variables but in the general case. The uniform distribution is only given for illustration purposes. My aim is to compute the n-th convolution of a random vector whith itself.

Comment: Excel is .. Excel. *grrr*.

Comment: I would imagine that this is easily answered with `n*RND()`.

Comment: n*RND() will just give n multiplied by the same random number, for n different numbers see my answer

Comment: Adding n uniform variables results in a non-uniform (Irwin-Hall) distribution. You can use `=NORM.S.INV(RAND())` to generate normal random variables and the sums are also normally distributed. (theoretically `RAND()` could return 0 but this case is so unlikely it can effectively be ignored)

Comment: @pnuts: yes the first is Binomial and the second is Uniform

Comment: @guitarthrower I can't use VBA in my case.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? The second formula allows you to generate n ranndom numbers

Comment: "could extend this formula to contain 50 terms RND" <--- use cumulative sum... Eg: say.. A1 = A2 = A3 = `=rand()` B2=A1+A2, B3 = B2+A3, drag downwards.. it'll still be random. Care to comment? ( :

Answer (score 4):

To sum 5 different random numbers between 0 and 1

`=SUMPRODUCT(RANDBETWEEN({0,0,0,0,0},100000))/100000`

or more generically

`=SUMPRODUCT(RANDBETWEEN(ROW(INDIRECT("1:5"))*0,100000))/100000`

replace 5 with any number

Comment: Of course `RAND()` never returns 1 but, yes, theoretically this can return 5....but only as often as it would return 0, `100,000^5 to 1`

Comment: much better solution. And based on my testing it actually resets the random number each time (as opposed to mine, which I don't think does). +1 to you.

Comment: imho this answers the question as it was originally posed and could be adapted for convolution - which could be the subject of a separate post. To get the full range of precision you can replace `100000` by `2^52` (also possibly simpler to substitute `^0-1` for `*0`)

Comment: I solved it by defining the named field random_vector =ROW(INDIRECT("1:5"))^0-1+RND() and then computing =SUM(random_vector)

Comment: @motsdujour Use Formulas > Evaluate Formula and you'll see that you're just getting the same random number reused in your solution.  In other words, the same as `5*RND()`. (I'm assuming that `RND()` is a regional variant of `RAND()`) The trouble is that, since RND() takes no arguments, we can't feed it a vector, hence RANDBETWEEN.

Comment: @ lori_m. Thanks for *0, Doh! I was "underthinking" that - changed my answer accordingly

Comment: What is the purpose of the INDIRECT()?  Also, if this goes into a named formula (which are evaluated as vector formulas) you don't need to fake ctrl-shift-enter by using SUMPRODUCT, right?

Comment: The question has been substantially edited, there was no mention of a named range in the original question. My assumption was that a worksheet formula was required. If you were to use `ROW(1:5)` on the worksheet that can change if rows are added or deleted, hence `INDIRECT`, but yes the formula works without it as you imply